# How do I replace my android app Google maps radius circle with a blue translucent one as in image?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

How do I replace my android app Google maps radius circle with a blue translucent one as in image also blue marker with blue circle?

I can make the circle have a particular outline and fill but it doesn't look anywhere near as nice as the one depicted in the image below. How do I do that? my code so far is below also.

Code:

```
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();


              LatLng latLng = new LatLng(28.982518, -81.542272);
              gooleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));


              Circle circle =  gooleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
              .center(new LatLng(28.982518, -81.542272))
              .radius(1000)
              .strokeColor(Color.RED)
              .fillColor(Color.PURPLE));

mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(center)
        .radius(radius)
        .strokeWidth(0f)
        .fillColor(0x550000FF));

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

Android xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Image:

> [image]

To confirm, what I'm trying to do is:

**Show the above effect, a dark blue circle with a translucent light blue fill as in above image**

Comment: Are you looking for `GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` call?

Comment: no sorry, I'm trying to create the above effect. A circular radius with a translucent blue

Comment: what do you mean it does not look anywhere near as nice..what does it look like

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(latlng)
        .radius(500)
        .strokeWidth(2)
        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
        .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#500084d3"));
        // Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB
        //   #AA is the alpha, or amount of transparency

    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

[image: translucent blue circle]

Comment: Thats a great solution..Can someone suggest me how to add the knob inside the circle. (Blue one in first Image).

Comment: The blue circle image is provided by the Maps API in this example. It is the user's current location. You can enable or disable the icon in the settings for the maps.
public final void setMyLocationEnabled (boolean enabled)
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29