# Show markers near the device in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an android app which is having several kinds of markers.

Here is my `MapsActivity.java` file.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;
List<MapLocation> restaurantList;
List<MapLocation> hotelList;
List<Marker> restaurantMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> hotelMarkers = new ArrayList<>();


MapLocation r1 = new MapLocation(6.9192,79.8950, "Mnhatten Fish Market" );
MapLocation r2 = new MapLocation(6.9017,79.9192, "Dinemore" );
MapLocation r3 = new MapLocation(6.9147,79.8778, "KFC" );
MapLocation r4 = new MapLocation(6.9036,79.9547, "McDonalds" );
MapLocation r5 = new MapLocation(6.8397,79.8758, "Dominos" );

MapLocation h1 = new MapLocation(6.9006,79.8533, "Hilton" );
MapLocation h2 = new MapLocation(6.8889,79.8567, "Galadari" );
MapLocation h3 = new MapLocation(6.8756,79.8608, "Hotel Lagoon Dining" );
MapLocation h4 = new MapLocation(6.7991,79.8767, "Aqua Pearl Lake Resort " );
MapLocation h5 = new MapLocation(6.5833,79.1667, "KZ Resort" );

//Buttons
private final LatLng LOCATION_COLOMBO = new LatLng(6.9270786,79.861243);
private final LatLng LOCATION_GALLE = new LatLng(6.0334009,80.218384);


private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    restaurantList = new ArrayList<>();
    hotelList =  new ArrayList<>();

    restaurantList.add(r1);
    restaurantList.add(r2);
    restaurantList.add(r3);
    restaurantList.add(r4);
    restaurantList.add(r5);

    hotelList.add(h1);
    hotelList.add(h2);
    hotelList.add(h3);
    hotelList.add(h4);
    hotelList.add(h5);

    // Give text to buttons
    Button buttonloc1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLoc1);
    buttonloc1.setText("Colombo");

    Button buttonloc2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLoc2);
    buttonloc2.setText("Galle");

    Button buttoncity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCity);
    buttoncity.setText("My Location");

    Button buttonremove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeMarker);
    buttonremove.setText("Remove");


    CheckBox checkRestaurants = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkRestaurants);
    checkRestaurants.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                showRestaurants();
            } else {
                hideRestaurants();
            }
        }
    });
    CheckBox checkHotels = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkHotels);
    checkHotels.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                showHotels();
            } else {
                hideHotels();
            }
        }
    });

    // Marker to Dinemore
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LOCATION_COLOMBO)
                    .title("I'm in Colombo :D")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
    );

    // Marker to Barista
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LOCATION_GALLE)
                    .title("I'm in Galle :D")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
    );



    //When touch again on the map marker title will hide
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    Location target = new Location("target");
    for(LatLng point : new LatLng[]{}) {
        target.setLatitude(point.latitude);
        target.setLongitude(point.longitude);
        if(location.distanceTo(target) <  100) {
            // bingo!
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    googleMap = map;
    setUpMap();
}

public void showRestaurants() {

    restaurantMarkers.clear();
    for (MapLocation loc : restaurantList){
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lon))
                .title(loc.title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lon)).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        restaurantMarkers.add(marker);
    }
}

public void showHotels() {

    hotelMarkers.clear();
    for (MapLocation loc : hotelList){
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lon))
                .title(loc.title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lon)).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        hotelMarkers.add(marker);
    }
}

public void hideRestaurants(){
    for (Marker marker : restaurantMarkers){
        marker.remove();
    }
}

public void hideHotels(){
    for (Marker marker : hotelMarkers){
        marker.remove();
    }
}

public void onClick_City(View v){
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
}
// When click on this button, Map shows the place of Dinemore
public void onClick_Loc1(View v) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_COLOMBO,10);
    mMap.animateCamera(update);
}

// When click on this button, Map shows the place of Barista
public void onClick_Loc2(View v) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_GALLE,10);
    mMap.animateCamera(update);
}

// To rmove All the Markers
public void onClick_Remove(View v){
    mMap.clear();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

public class MapLocation {
    public MapLocation(double lt, double ln, String t){
        lat = lt;
        lon = ln;
        title = t;
    }
    public double lat;
    public double lon;
    public String title;
}
```

}

Now, what I need to do is, I need to show only markers which is near the device.

Here are the steps what I need to do.

1. Identify a circle round of the device area (500m)
2. Identify the Markers inside this circle
3. Show the identified Markers
4. Re-identify the circle when the device is moving
5. Need to change the circle and markers when the device is traveling.

Can I do this in Android? If can please help me to do this or post articles that might help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user5259714 Hi, I'm facing the same challenge, if possible please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351094/get-nearby-places-from-a-custom-markers?noredirect=1#comment81704920_47351094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i can help you with two links.

first of all i will accept that you know how to get your location from maps.after that for drawing a circle follow this guide

[How to replace a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907317/how-do-i-replace-my-android-app-google-maps-radius-circle-with-a-blue-translucen)

after that for the radius i can show you a method by the link so you can follow it and modify it for yourself

[Detect nearby places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284708/how-to-constantly-detect-nearby-marker-locations-from-current-location-in-google)

so follow this and you will get your answers.

**EDIT**

change your locations to latlng as follows;

for r1:

LatLng POINTA = new LatLng(6.9192,79.8950);
//do the same for the others and put it into array belove.it is simple please do not expect direct answer and work for it.

```
for(LatLng point : new LatLng[]{POINTA, POINTB, POINTC, POINTD}) {
        target.setLatitude(point.latitude);
        target.setLongitude(point.longitude);
        if(location.distanceTo(target) < METERS_100) {
            // bingo!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284708/how-to-constantly-detect-nearby-marker-locations-from-current-location-in-google/33074855#33074855 and METERS_100 gives me an error. Do yuo know why?

Comment: maybe he has a model class for meters.have you tried just writing 100 as an int instead of it?

Comment: 100 works. Can you just look at the code I cannot pass my r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,h1,h2,h3,h4 and h5 values into for loop like his code.

Comment: Really sorry for asking silly questions. Problem solved. Now I could load the markers inside my area. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to simply have a limit to the distance you need the markers visible:

In my previous project, I was syncing down from a server n number of locations within 100 miles for instance. You see, this makes sure that you ONLY get what you need as opposed to having a lot of locations that you won't need.

So, I sync down say 15 nearby locations and add the markers to the map. Then when a user moves, I sync again to make sure I get ONLY the nearby business locations. This worked for me without any problems.

I hope this helps you; so in short:

1. Sync down n number of locations assuming you know the locations ahead of time in your server (remotely) - you can get the nearest locations using a SQL query (statement). To do this, you will need both latitude and longitude for each location.
2. Once the syncing is done, simply loop through the data and set the markers - based on the latitude and longitudes of the locations!

That is all you really need!

Good luck!

Comment: Can you show how to this in my code. I'm new to Andrdoid. :(

Answer (score 0):

Surely You can do this.

You can check distance of your device from marker `onLocationChanged` . Here you can also re-identify circle.

Comment: Are sure this helps to identify Markers inside the circle of my location. Can you show how in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. It will help you.

http://danielgultom.blogspot.com/2011/01/create-radius-around-point-in-google.html?showComment=1444634924438